# Mocha running multiple 'its' in series

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'd like to run a series of tests which build on data used in previous tests.

How can this achieve it with something similar to:

```
describe(``,()=>{
    let t = true;
    it(`test1`,()=>assert(t));
    t = false;
    it(`test2`,()=>assert(!t));
});
```

which fails because line 3 is executed after line 4.

Comment: `it('test1', ()=> { assert(t); t = false; });`?

Comment: O yeah. it really is that simple. I thought i tried that with the actual (complicated) version of my test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not recommended to make tests depend on state that is set up by other tests.** As a test suite gets more complex it is **extremely** useful to be able to use Mocha's `grep` option, or be able to use `it.only` temporarily so that when you have a test that fails, *you can concentrate on running only that test*. However, if your test depends on other tests running before it in order to run properly, you cannot isolate it. If you go into the debugger and set a breakpoint on a line that gets hit a dozen times before the actual test you care about, this gets old fast.

In the example code you show, you could do:

```
describe(``,()=>{
    let t = true;
    it(`test1`,()=>assert(t));
    it(`test2`,() => {
      t = false; // Set the state here.
      assert(!t);
    });
});
```

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130584/mocha-running-multiple-its-in-series#comment97002780_55130584), Nik suggested setting `t` in `test1`. I suggest setting it in `test2`. With the code I suggest above you could run `mocha --grep test2`, or temporarily change `` it(`test2`... `` to `` it.only(`test2`... `` and your test would run just fine.

However, I suspect your actual code is more complex than the example you gave and may actually be using some significant code to set the state for your tests. If you want to segregate the test setup code from the test itself, you could do this:

```
describe(``,() => {
    describe("", () => {
      let t;
      before(() => {
        t = someSubtantialInitialization();
      });

      it(`test1`, () => ...);
    });

    describe("", () => {
      let t;
      before(() => {
        t = someOtherSubstantialInitialization();
      });

      it(`test2`,() => ...);
    });
});
```

Mocha has `before` and `beforeEach` hooks but it does not have a `beforeJustThisOneTest` hook. You can associate a hook with a single test by putting the test and the hook in their own `describe` block.